# Reference to the iteration number in Java's foreach

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

**How can you refer to the index of an array in the foreach?**

My code

```
String[] name = { "hello", "world" };
for ( int k : name[k] ) {
   --- cut ---
}
```

I expecting that the foreach -loop will

```
1. set k = 0 in first iteration so that name[0] works correctly
2. set k = 1 in the next iteration...
```

I get the error message

> foreach not applicable to expression type

Comment: Can you provide more information as to why you believe that you need an index? Are you really doing something that is position dependent, or are you simply doing something with each string in the array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because the index is not available when using the `foreach` syntax. You have to use *traditional* iteration if you need the index:

```
for (int i =0; i < names.length; i++) {
   String name = names[i];
}
```

If you *do not need* the index, the standard `foreach` will suffice:

```
for (String name : names) {
    //...
}
```

**EDIT**: *obviously you can get the index using a counter, but then you have a variable available outside the scope of the loop, which I think is undesirable*

Comment: In your second paragraph, I think you meant to write *index* not *syntax*.

Comment: The first for loop won't with a non-indexed Collection.

Comment: @Steve: yes ... but the question is asking about an array, not a Collection.

Answer (score 3):

Only way would be to keep track yourself with a counter.

```
int cnt = 0;
String[] names = new String[10];
for (String s : names) {
   ...do something...
   cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Best answer.  Basically, you can't but there's no problem in creating your own counter.

Comment: If you want a counter, wouldn't you be better off just using a normal for loop?

Comment: @ColinD - it's a toss up, but I find the foreach loops easier to read in general.

Comment: @downvote - care to explain?  Show my another way WITH A FOREACH loop to keep track of the index, since that was the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. Inside an enhanced for-statement, you can only iterate over an [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). You can't do anything else inside it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Integer index = null;
    String[] tokens = new String[] { "I", "Love", "You" };
    List<String> arrs = Arrays.asList(tokens);
    for (String arr : arrs) {
        index = arrs.indexOf(arr);
        System.out.println("Index of " + arr + " is: " + index);
    }
```

Comment: And now try to do the same with duplicates in the array.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for asking me to check this. I got the following output when checked with String[] tokens = new String[] { "I", "Love", "You", "You" }; Output: 
** ====== **
** Index of I is: 0 ** 
** Index of Love is: 1 **
** Index of You is: 2 ** 
** Index of You is: 2 ** 

I need to check the exact reason for this but for the timing...adding another answer to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

With your example, the foreach loop should be used like this (the plural `names` is a better name for an array of names than `name`):

```
String[] names = { "hello", "world" };
for ( String name : names ) {
   // do something with the name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an counter. Just do

```
String[] name = { "hello", "world" };
for ( String s : name ) {
   --- cut ---
   System.out.println(s);
   --- cut ---
}
```

Which will output

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is problem with index accuracy converting array to list when array consists of duplicates. For the timing, recommending this solution on top of using enhanced for-loop for list.

```
    String[] tokens = new String[] { "I", "Love", "You", "You" };
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("token at index "+i+" is: "+tokens[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your using the for each loop incorrectly. It automatically gives you a reference to each element in what you are iterating over, and there is to need to index. The correct way, in this case, would be the following:

```
String[] name = {"hello", "world"};
for(String s : name){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If you need more flexibility in accessing the elements of an iterable object, you can use the iterator directly. Arrays don't provide iterators, so I've use a List here.

```
List<String> name = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"hello", "world"});

for(Iterator<String> it = name.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    String currentName = it.next();
    System.out.println(currentName);
    it.remove();
}
```